# How should I specify my random effect when it is correlated to a fixed effect?

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, experiment-design, lme4-nlme

I want to perform a GLMM on my data in R using `lme4`. I have one response variable measured on more than 250 individuals. For each of those individuals, a categorical variable, lets call it `Cat` (fixed effect), can take one of five values (A, B, C, D or E). Measurements were taken during ten independent experiments, which is represented with the categorical variable `Block` (random effect), taking values 1 to 10. I also have a bunch of other covariates, but they are not of interest for my question here.

What troubles me is that `Cat`is not equally distributed within `Block`. Blocks 1 to 5 contain observations of A, B and C, blocks 6 to 8 contain observations of D and E, and blocks 9 and 10 contain observations of E only. `Cat` and `Block` are thus "correlated" (I don't know if I can use this term for categorical variables?). This is illustrated using the `sizetree` function from package `plotrix`:

> sizetree(dataset[,c(2,7)])

[image]

How should I specifiy my random term? For example, if levels D and E are associated to low values of my response variable compared to A, B and C, blocks 5 to 10 will have low values. I am afraid that a part of the variance will be attributed to `Block` instead of being attributed to `Cat`if I only use `(1|Block)`. Do I need to nest `Cat` within `Block` as `(1|Block/Cat)` to account for the fact that given levels of `Cat` are not encountered in all levels of `Block`?

More generally, should we be concerned about this type of "correlation" between random and fixed effects?

Comment: `(1|Block/Cat)` is equal to `(1|Block)+(1|Block:Cat)` so it's just adding one more random effect term and will not get around the problem you are talking about. The problem is that your `Cat` is confounded with your `Block` and there is nothing you can do about it. Using `Cat+(1|Block)` is sensible and yes, part of the `Cat` effect might end up attributed to `Block`, but alas. That was an unfortunate experiment design.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @amoeba! I will then use `(1|Block)`, and the only thing I can do is being very cautious when discussing the results... Yes, I agree with this design being far from ideal, and the experiment was initially designed to be balanced. But it was impossible to get individuals belonging to all levels of `Cat` at the same time, so we had no other choice but to split the experiment between `Cat` levels...